# Expose ports with rootless podman

Tags: rhel, podman

I am trying to expose port 8080 using rootless podman on RHEL 8.3.

The podman version I am using is:

```sh
$ podman --version
podman version 2.2.1
```

I am using a simple `Flask` API to test it:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from the container!\n"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

The Containerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN pip3 install flask

COPY app.py app.py

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT python3 app.py
```

I am building the image using:

```sh
$ podman build -t testapi .
```

I am creating a pod and start a container within that pod

```sh
$ podman pod create --name testpod -p 8080:5000
$
$ podman run -d --rm --name testapi --pod testpod testapi
```

All containers are running as expected:

```sh
$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                     COMMAND  CREATED             STATUS            PORTS                   NAMES
85289290cc7a  localhost/testapi:latest           3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds ago  0.0.0.0:8080->5000/tcp  testapi
4b1ac2354a1a  k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2               About a minute ago  Up 3 seconds ago  0.0.0.0:8080->5000/tcp  81aa31a38084-infra
```

However, I cannot connect to the port:

```sh
$ telnet <IP> 8080
Trying <IP>...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

When I use netstat to see which port are in use I get this:

```sh
$ netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      638593/containers-r 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

And using lsof I get:

```sh
$ lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
exe     638593   ds   13u  IPv6 593362      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

When I do the same thing using rootfull podman, it works, i.e.:

```sh
$ sudo podman pod create --name testpod -p 8080:5000 
$ sudo podman run -d --rm --name testapi --pod testpod testapi
```

Now the response is:

```sh
$ telnet 10.100.2.220 8080
Trying 10.100.2.220...
Connected to 10.100.2.220.
```

netstat returns:

```sh
$ netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

and lsof:

```sh
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
conmon  639312   root    5u  IPv4 590239      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

Is there a way to expose a port using rootless podman so I can access it away from the podman host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check this step when using rootless pod:

$ telnet  8080
Trying ...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host

I have reproduced your environnement and your image, and I didn't found any problems.

PS: it may be something related to firewalld, try to open port 8080.

```
# firewall-cmd --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent 
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested the same on Podman 3.1.2 (Ubuntu 20.04.2).
It seems to work. Maybe your Podman version is too old and contains some bug?

```
esjolund@laptop:~/test$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN pip3 install flask

COPY app.py app.py

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT python3 app.py
esjolund@laptop:~/test$ cat app.py 
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from the container!\n"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
esjolund@laptop:~/test$ podman build -t testapi .
STEP 1: FROM python:3.6-alpine
✔ docker.io/library/python:3.6-alpine
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 8b0340cff2c8 done  
Copying blob c89910f38943 done  
Copying blob a7ad1a75a999 done  
Copying blob 5545670c3922 done  
Copying blob 540db60ca938 done  
Copying config 118f82a946 done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
STEP 2: RUN pip3 install flask
Collecting flask
  Downloading Flask-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous>=2.0
  Downloading itsdangerous-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting Jinja2>=3.0
  Downloading Jinja2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug>=2.0
  Downloading Werkzeug-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (288 kB)
Collecting click>=7.1.2
  Downloading click-8.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1.tar.gz (18 kB)
Collecting dataclasses
  Downloading dataclasses-0.8-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: MarkupSafe
  Building wheel for MarkupSafe (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for MarkupSafe (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for MarkupSafe: filename=MarkupSafe-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=9743 sha256=93d0dc7d9d4546b1b9b0a9b4c14c7313c101969f3442c00d180f37a3f253bc6c
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/05/46/9b/189d9acb1f643857fb8ad990ca04c02509c35d3ad6fac81794
Successfully built MarkupSafe
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, dataclasses, Werkzeug, Jinja2, itsdangerous, click, flask
Successfully installed Jinja2-3.0.1 MarkupSafe-2.0.1 Werkzeug-2.0.1 click-8.0.0 dataclasses-0.8 flask-2.0.0 itsdangerous-2.0.1
WARNING: Running pip as root will break packages and permissions. You should install packages reliably by using venv: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
--> cddad03925e
STEP 3: COPY app.py app.py
--> 56afbc68fea
STEP 4: EXPOSE 5000
--> 0d76f34a2c3
STEP 5: ENTRYPOINT python3 app.py
STEP 6: COMMIT testapi
--> e40c443149a
e40c443149a7cc16cbecfd2e8dab059ed4c148982b84b536ac62a16dc9869a75
esjolund@laptop:~/test$ podman pod create --name testpod -p 8080:5000
25c16eb23ccf256677ad643a361d8f3b1197495a33c0378b6938f8884e20787e
esjolund@laptop:~/test$ podman run -d --rm --name testapi --pod testpod testapi 
d6e112e00e29603e489863802f6cf7f2854c5aa4a24da479a1df48fb154627d4
esjolund@laptop:~/test$ curl localhost:8080
Hello from the container!
esjolund@laptop:~/test$ podman --version
podman version 3.1.2
esjolund@laptop:~/test$ nc  -4 -z -v localhost 8080
Connection to localhost 8080 port [tcp/http-alt] succeeded!
esjolund@laptop:~/test$
```

RHEL 8.4 has now been released. I think it contains a newer Podman version that you might want to try.